# Node.js issue in try-catch with then-catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, try-catch, es6-promise

I write a try-catch function and inside the try, I execute then catch promises.  I want to throw the error to try-catch, catch. I don't know how to explain it. please review my code, and you will understand the problem here:

```
try {
  function().then(result =>{
    if(result){
      // do something
      function2().then(result =>{
        if(result){
        // do something
        }else{
        throw "bad request";
        }
       }).catch((error)=>{
        throw error
       })
    }else{
      throw "not found";
    }
  }).catch(error =>{
    throw error
  });
}catch (error){
  callback(BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Can I do this or not, or there is another way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you put the `callback(BAD_REQUEST)` inside the first catch?

Comment: @DavideBulbarelli  cause because there are lots of then-catch inside the try-catch function when I call 'callback' inside all catch function it will be repeatable code there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misconception on how Promises work.

When you call a Promise, that's an asynchronus call, the main thread doesn't know when it's going to finish. For that reason, you have to use "then()", so that code will be executed whenever the promise ends.

For the same reason, you can't catch an error that you don't know when it will occur. So, that try-catch block it's actually doing nothing.

What to do? Well, if you need to know how that promise ends, you could use `await` operator.

Also, you could have a global error listener (depends on which platform and language are you using), but that's a different question.

Comment: I re-edit my code. I can simply call back inside the catch, but here I have a lot of then catch calls, so it will be repeatable. that's why I try to do throw error from the catch and  catch on try-catch catch and do one callback..  can you understand what I'm trying to do here

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do, but that's not the way it goes. The try-catch outside the promise won't work because it's a different code flow than the one of the promise. Do you understand that or do you want me to modify my answer with an example?

Answer (score 0):

`.then` receives a callback function. To catch the error you have to put try-catch inside .then callback.

**What to do?**

To catch error of a promise you can either use `.catch()` or use modern async/await.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point of view, you can use await/async ([check this guide](https://javascript.info/async-await)).

```
try {
  firstResult = await function1();
  if(firstResult) {
    secondResult = await function2();
    if(secondResult){
       //do something
    }
    else {
       throw "bad request"
    }
  }
  else {
    throw "not found"
  }
}
catch (err) {
   callback(err)
}
```

Is this what you want to do?